# Error in calling POST method on fetch method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, webapi

I am receiving below error when calling my WebAPI from react application using fetch().then().then().

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

React code:

```
function handleSubmit() {
console.log(selectedClass, textAreaData);
let classInfo = { className: selectedClass, attendenceData: textAreaData };
fetch("http://localhost:58882/GenerateExcel", {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  },
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  body: JSON.stringify(classInfo)
})
  .then(response => response)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

}

WebAPI:

```
[Route("GenerateExcel")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GenerateExcel([FromBody] ClassInput input)
    {
        string path = "";
        string selectedClass = "6"; string attendance;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        switch (selectedClass)
        {//some logic}
}

public class ClassInput
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string AttendenceData { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine when its GET.

Comment: Why are you setting your mode to no-cors?

Comment: webapi is a different application. if i dont set No-Cors, then i get cors error.

Comment: Wouldn't that be your problem then? CORS must be enabled for API's to communicate with web apps otherwise you will get an error. I only asked because I have never seen this flag used.

Comment: yes, i think that was the problem.